# $.each function to show each DIV, one at a time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following function. To make a long story short, I have 4 divs that I want to apply an `init` class to. The `init` class essentially shows the 4 divs.

It works as it should, however it shows all 4 divs at the same time, which is not what I want. I want to show 1 div, then the next, then the next, etc.

Where am I going wrong?

```
$('.campaign-item').waypoint({                          

    handler: function() {

        var $this = $(this);

        $this.each(function(i) {

            setTimeout(function() {
                $this.addClass('init');
            }, i * 500 );
        });                         
    },
    offset: '60%'
});
```

Comment: `$this` refers to the whole group, not just the single element you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('.campaign-item').each(function (i) {

    var $this = $(this);

    $this.waypoint({
        handler: function() {
            setTimeout(function() {
                    $this.addClass('init');
            }, i * 500 );                                                         
        },
        offset: '60%'
    });
});
```

Comment: Still shows all 4 divs at once...doesn't show one after the another.

Answer (score 3):

You need to add the class to each individual element, not to all of them.

```
var $this = $(this);
$this.each(function(i,v){
    setTimeout(function(){
        $(v).addClass('init');
    }, i * 500 );
});
```

Comment: Still shows all 4 divs at once...doesn't show one after the another.

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle?

Comment: Doesn't look like the delay on the timeout is even working - I set it to 5000 - nothing. No delay. Hmm

Comment: Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/6cP2Y/  Can we see an example of your code?  Also, what's `.waypoint()`?

Comment: Hmm. Maybe it's the plug-in. Waypoints runs js code when you scroll to a particular element... http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/#about

Comment: As per PhistucK's answer, the `$.each` function had to be OUTSIDE the `waypoint` code. There was some conflict. +1 for the help! Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that a jQuery object contains a collection of the objects that match your selector. "$(this)" is that collection. The "each" function gives you access to the individual elements in that collection with the returned second parameter ("function(index, element)"). In your code you are trying to add your "init" class to every member of the collection because "$this" IS the entire collection. You need to add the class to the second parameter returned in each iteration of your each function.